# Luxon date formatting from object as moment does

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, iso, luxon

How can I pass a string object inside a Luxon hours formatting?

```
var message = "2020-10-05 17:24:23.456354"
```

Kind of a:  `{DateTime(message).local().toFormat("HH:mm")}`

Which is not working.

In moment.js would be: `{moment(message).format("HH:mm")}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{DateTime.fromISO(message).toFormat("HH:mm")}